# Hi im not that good at code can you help me to see why im getting errors

Tags: python

```
def two_coin_toss():

    import random

    name = input("Hi, what is your name?")

    print ("Well,", name, ",it is good to meet you!")

    counter=0

    while not(counter<5):

        print
        print ("Here are your possible calls:")
        print (" 1. Two heads")
        print (" 2. Two tails")
        print (" 3. One head and one tail")
        call = input("What is your call, 1, 2 or 3? ")
        counter=counter+1
        print

    print ("You have called ",)

    if call==1:
        print ("two heads")
    if call==2:
        print ("two tails")
    if call==3:
        print ("head and tail")

    bet = input("what is your bet? $")

    toss=random.randint(1,3)
    print
    print ("The toss is:",)

    if toss==1:
        print ("two heads")
    else:
        if toss==2:
```

I have no idea what im doing the aim of this game is to Request for client’s name
Taking of call of heads, tails or head and tail
Validation of call input
Validation of bet
Calculation of toss
Informing user of win or loss
Display running total of user winner/loss total
All bets and results must be stored in an external text file
No single bet may exceed $20
No user can bet more than 20 times in a single session
Details of any settings i.e. maximum bet, maximum number of bets in a single session, bet to payout ratios must be stored in a separate external text file
Thx in advance

Comment: why did you wait until Sunday evening to do your homework?

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself this: what does `(counter<5)` mean when `counter` is zero. Then, ask yourself what `not(counter<5)` means. And finally, ask yourself how that effects this: `while not(counter<5)`